# how to use complex model in kendo mvvm

Tags: jquery, kendo-ui, kendo-mvvm, kendo-combobox

I'm using kendo mvvm framework for my project.
The main idea is - I'm trying to reuse CustomerComboboxViewModel  model in different  places.
I have next code:

```js
var CustomerComboboxViewModel = kendo.data.ObservableObject.extend({
    selected: null,
    customers: new kendo.data.DataSource({ // scheme description })
});

var NewProjectDialogViewModel = kendo.data.ObservableObject.extend({
    customerControlViewModel: new CustomerComboboxViewModel()   
});

var PageViewModel = kendo.data.ObservableObject.extend({
    
    customerControlViewModel: new CustomerComboboxViewModel(),
    dialogViewModel: new NewProjectDialogViewModel(),
    
    init: function(){
      that.get("customerControlViewModel")
          .customers
          .data([// some date her]);
      }
    
});


$("#page").bind(new PageViewModel())
```

```html
<div id="page">
    <input
    data-role="combobox"
    data-bind="source: customerControlViewModel.customers, value: customerControlViewModel.selected"
    data-text-field="companyname"
    data-value-field="id" />
    
     <div id="newProjectDialog"
            data-role="dialog"            
            data-modal="true">

                <input
                    data-role="combobox"
                    data-text-field="companyname"
                    data-value-field="id"
                    data-bind="source: dialogViewModel.customerControlViewModel.customers, value: dialogViewModel.customerControlViewModel.selected }"
                     />
    </div>
</div>
```

After init function invoked - both of my models (customerControlViewModel, dialogViewModel) will be populated with the same data. I don't understand how they are related to each other.

Answer (score 0):

Use this

```js
var CustomerComboboxViewModel = kendo.data.ObservableObject.extend({
    selected: null,
    customers: new kendo.data.DataSource({ // scheme description })
});

var NewProjectDialogViewModel = CustomerComboboxViewModel .extend({
       
});

var PageViewModel = kendo.data.ObservableObject.extend({
    dialogViewModel: new NewProjectDialogViewModel(),
   customers: new kendo.data.DataSource(),
    selected: null,
    init: function(){
        this.set("customers",  this.get("dialogViewModel.customers");
         this.set("selected",  this.get("dialogViewModel.selected");
      }
    
});

$("#page").bind(PageViewModel);
```

```html
<div id="page">
    <input
    data-role="combobox"
    data-bind="source: customers, value: selected"
    data-text-field="companyname"
    data-value-field="id" />
    
     <div id="newProjectDialog"
            data-role="dialog"            
            data-modal="true">

                <input
                    data-role="combobox"
                    data-text-field="companyname"
                    data-value-field="id"
                    data-bind="source: customers, value: selected }"
                     />
    </div>
</div>
```